# how to access array with data in another array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

Assume I have array A and B

B contain data that index array of Array A

( Example B(1,:) = [2 3] it mean that I want to access data of array A(2,3) )

I want to show the all data A that have in B

I try to code like this

A(B(:,1),B(:,2))

however when I try to run the program it seem wrong ( like I have B contain data 100 x 2 it should produce 100 results but it produces 200 instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
A(sub2ind(size(A),B(:,1),B(:,2)))
```